# Why are all the tasks completed in asyncio.wait() when I clearly indicate that I want only the first one completed?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm trying to fetch some data from OpenSubtitles using asyncio and then download a file who's information is contained in that data. I want to fetch that data and download the file at the same time using asyncio.

The problem is that I want to wait for 1 task from the list `tasks` to finish before commencing with the rest of the tasks in the list or the `download_tasks`. The reason for this is that in `self._perform_query()` I am writing information to a file and in `self._download_and_save_file()` I am reading that same information from that file. So in other words, the `download_tasks` need to wait for at least one task in `tasks` to finish before starting.

I found out I can do that with `asyncio.wait(return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)` but for some reason it is not working properly:

```
payloads = [create_payloads(entry) for entry in retreive(table_in_database)] 
tasks = [asyncio.create_task(self._perform_query(payload, proxy)) for payload in payloads]
download_tasks = [asyncio.create_task(self._download_and_save_file(url, proxy) for url in url_list]

done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
print(done)
print(len(done))
print(pending)
print(len(pending))
await asyncio.wait(download_tasks)
```

The output is completely different than expected. It seems that out of 3 tasks in the list `tasks` all 3 of them are being completed despite me passing `asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED`. Why is this happening?

```
{<Task finished coro=<SubtitleDownloader._perform_query() done, defined at C:\Users\...\subtitles.py:71> result=None>, <Task finished coro=<SubtitleDownloader._perform_query() done, defined at C:\Users\...\subtitles.py:71> result=None>, <Task finished coro=<SubtitleDownloader._perform_query() done, defined at C:\Users\...\subtitles.py:71> result=None>}
3
set()
0
Exiting
```

As far as I can tell, the code in `self._perform_query()` shouldn't affect this problem. Here it is anyway just to make sure:

```
async def _perform_query(self, payload, proxy):
    try:
        query_result = proxy.SearchSubtitles(self.opensubs_token, [payload], {"limit": 25})
    except Fault as e:
        raise "A fault has occurred:\n{}".format(e)
    except ProtocolError as e:
        raise "A ProtocolError has occurred:\n{}".format(e)
    else:
        if query_result["status"] == "200 OK":
            with open("dl_links.json", "w") as dl_links_json:
                result = query_result["data"][0]
                subtitle_name = result["SubFileName"]
                download_link = result["SubDownloadLink"]
                download_data = {"download link": download_link,
                                 "file name": subtitle_name}
                json.dump(download_data, dl_links_json)
        else:
            print("Wrong status code: {}".format(query_result["status"]))
```

For now, I've been testing this without running `download_tasks` but I have included it here for context. Maybe I am going about this problem in a completely wrong manner. If so, I would much appreciate your input!

Edit:

The problem was very simple as answered below. `_perform_query` wasn't an awaitable function, instead it ran synchronously. I changed that by editing the file writing part of `_perform_query` to be asynchronous with `aiofiles`:

```
def _perform_query(self, payload, proxy):
    query_result = proxy.SearchSubtitles(self.opensubs_token, [payload], {"limit": 25})
    if query_result["status"] == "200 OK":
        async with aiofiles.open("dl_links.json", mode="w") as dl_links_json:
            result = query_result["data"][0]
            download_link = result["SubDownloadLink"]
            await dl_links_json.write(download_link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED` doesn't guarantee that only a single task will complete. It guarantees that the wait will complete as soon as a task completes, but it is perfectly possible that other tasks complete "at the same time", which for asyncio means in the same iteration of the event loop. Consider, for example, the following code:

```
async def noop():
    pass

async def main():
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
        [noop(), noop(), noop()], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    print(len(done), len(pending))

asyncio.run(main())
```

This prints `3 0`, just like your code. Why?

`asyncio.wait` does two things: it submits the coroutines to the event loop, and it sets up callbacks to notify it when any of them is complete. However, the `noop` coroutine doesn't contain an `await`, so none of the calls to `noop()` suspends, each just does its thing and immediately returns. As a result, all three coroutine instances finish within the same pass of the event loop. `wait` is then informed that all three coroutines have finished, a fact it dutifully reports.

If you change `noop` to await a random sleep, e.g. change `pass` to `await asyncio.sleep(0.1 * random.random())`, you get the expected behavior. With an `await` the coroutines no longer complete at the same time, and `wait` will report the first one as soon as it detects it.

This reveals the true underlying issue with your code: `_perform_query` **doesn't await**. This indicates that you are not using an async underlying library, or that you are using it incorrectly. The call to `SearchSubtitles` likely simply blocks the event loop, which *appears* to work in trivial tests, but breaks essential asyncio features such as concurrent execution of tasks.

Comment: Thank you for the great clarification! By adding asynchronous file writing in the `_perform_query` I get the inteded result.

Comment: @917k Consider also using an awaitable for `SearchSubtitles`, which (I suspect) takes the majority of time. Writing out the files using `aiofiles` only appears to fix the issue, while the more pressing problem of `SearchSubtitles` blocking the coroutine (and the event loop with it) remains, as you'll discover if you try to e.g. download multiple subtitles in parallel.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But when I try creating a task from `SearchSubtitles` and then awaiting it I get `TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got {'status': '200 OK', ...`.
How should I await that method if it is part of the OpenSubtitles API?

Comment: @917k You need to find an async API for the functionality you need - for example, use [`aiohttp`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp) instead of `requests`. In your case, you would need to find or build an async version of the subtitle search API. The situation is improving, but the availability of async interfaces is one of the challenges of using asyncio at this point. Finally, if you must use a blocking interface, you can use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to call the blocking function.

Comment: Could you expand more on how I would use `run_in_executor`? What would calling that function exactly acomplish?

Comment: @917k It would pass off the blocking code to a thread pool, and return an object that you can `await` in asyncio. (The linked documentation provides a usage example.) This allows the event pool to continue doing other things while waiting for the blocking code to finish. Also note that I am only advocating `run_in_executor` as **last resort**, if you cannot find an async API for what you need to do.